# Jenkins pipeline DSL automatically abort input

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using the new Jenkins pipeline DSL which I really like.  My `Jenkinsfile` is probably fairly typical and compiles / unit tests code in the `master` branch of GIT using maven, does a docker build, deploys to staging etc.  Towards the end of the pipeline there is a manual step where a user has to confirm if a build goes to production e.g.

```
stage name: 'Production Deploy', concurrency:1
input 'Do you want to deploy to production?'
node {
    sh "./bin/production-deploy.sh"
}
```

However, the build blocks until someone accepts / declines.  Is there a way to automatically decline the `input` if someone else kicks the build off (by merging code to the `master` branch)?

Comment: Separate the CI pipeline of CD pipeline. In the CI pipeline you build, test, deploy from develop stage to staging stage, the someone validate the staging deploy and in a second step you ececute the DC pipeline in is when you deploy to production stage. that way you have an independent livecycle develoment process and an independen delivery process.

Comment: Are you suggesting there is 2 pipelines for each project?  Is this the best practice way of doing this?  I thought (from reading the book "Continuous Delivery" http://martinfowler.com/books/continuousDelivery.html) that you want all stages (compile -> staging -> QA -> etc -> production) in a single build pipeline

Comment: in your case, yes. In the case of the book proposes, go well when you have the entire process automated and there is not pause or human interactions. And you have implement in your infrastructure some stuffs as blue/green deployments, that allow validate your deploy in aVM node while other VM node is given production service.

Comment: Does everyone else agree with this?  Maybe @johnnynemonic you create an answer and see how many people vote it up?

Answer (score 0):

I sugest you separate the Continuos Integration pipeline of Continuos Delivery pipeline. In the CI pipeline you build, test, deploy from develop stage to staging stage, then someone validate the staging deploy and when all staging tests are OK in a next step you execute the DC pipeline; is when you deploy to production stage. in that way you have an independent livecycle develoment process and an independent delivery process.